# UDP packet loss in aws EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, udp, packet-loss

I have an application that listens to a particular port in AWS where it is hosted. I will be receiving UDP packets from a number of AWS servers to this port. The problem I am facing is I am able to receive the packets from all the AWS servers only on a random basis. i.e, Consider AWS1 AWS2 AWS3 are 3 AWS servers which will send the UDP packets to the AWS server where my application is hosted, then the scenario is like this, if I am getting the packets from AWS2 first I will receive the packets from AWS2 alone to the particular port my application is listening, I won't receive any packets from the other two AWS servers. If gets from AWS3 first then I will get packets only from that server but not from the remaining 2 servers I have configured inbound as 0.0.0.0/0 i.e, all traffic for all protocols, but still this problem persists.

Can anybody help me please..

Comment: I am also experiencing the same problem, and the randomness I am getting is time randomness. i.e. [2018-07-27 - 2018-07-31] loss most UDP, [2018-07-31 - 2018-08-01] UDP normal again, [2018-08-01 - 2018-08-03] loss most UDP again. I originally was going to blame on my code, but from this post and other seems like it is AWS problem. Also, did you find any solution regarding this issue?

Comment: Sorry @NgSekLong , we didn't got any solution for this...